# Using AppSettings.AllKeys 

Tags: c#, web-config

I am trying to use App keys as below :

```
<add key="APPLE" value="TESTER"/>
<add key="apple" value="TESTER"/>
<add key="ORANGE" value="DEVELOPER"/>
```

Now the Problem is that when I am using AllKeys as:

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains(Fruits)
```

AllKeys just contains key for APPLE and ORANGE and nothing comes for "apple".
Is it because, both "apple" and "APPLE" has same value as "TESTER "

or else Allkeys conflicts between keys for "APPLE" and "apple"

Any pointers ??

Comment: The key is case insensitive, so *apple* and *APPLE* are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppSettings is a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) who's default comparer is the [`CaseInsensitiveComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.caseinsensitivecomparer.aspx)

Comment: looks quite true... but strange for the fact that it is case in-sensitive